# Not able to add custom fields to django-registration

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-registration

I extended `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail`

```
class CustomRegistrationFormUniqueEmail(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First name'), max_length=30,required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Last name'), max_length=30, required=True)
    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        new_user = super(CustomRegistrationFormUniqueEmail, self).save(profile_callback=profile_callback)
        new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        return new_user
```

then changed view

```
#       form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        form = CustomRegistrationFormUniqueEmail(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
```

But, still I see default form which contains four fields only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently implemented such a form. Here's what we've done:

- Create a new `backend` (just copy it from the default backend to start with)

  ```
  registration/
      backends/
          default/
          custom/ # <- your new backend
  ```

  ...
- In the new `urls.py` adjust the backend arguments

  ```
  ...
  { 'backend': 'registration.backends.custom.DefaultBackend' },
  ...
  ```
- Create a `forms.py` under `custom`. Adjust this form to your liking (fields and validations)
- In the `registration/urls.py` point to the proper backend:

  ```
   # from registration.backends.default.urls import *
   from registration.backends.custom.urls import *
  ```

That should work. Particularly this works because:

- Your `custom/__init__.py` will have a `DefaultBackend` class with a `get_form_class` method:

  ```
  def get_form_class(self, request):
      """
      Return the default form class used for user registration.
      """
      return RegistrationForm
  ```
- And you import your own `RegistrationForm` in that file, too:

  ```
  from registration.backends.custom.forms import RegistrationForm
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, off hand, why it isn't working but I am pretty sure you do *not* need to edit django-registration's `views.py` ...  you can pass your new `CustomRegistrationFormUniqueEmail` as an argument in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look here [Extending django-registration using signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114976/extending-django-registration-using-signals) and here http://dmitko.ru/?p=546