# Pass arguments from django-registration to django-profiles when user registers

Tags: python, django

I'm using both django-registrations and django-profiles. When the user registers I'd like to ask them to fill in the form fields from profiles as well as the usual username and password. How do I combine these two into one sign up page?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I [answered a question (on SO) on adjusting the `RegistrationForm` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934867/problem-in-adding-custom-fields-to-django-registration/2935578#2935578). In this `RegistrationForm` you could prompt the user for his profile information. You should process this data in the `register` method of the `DefaultBackend`.