# Models does not create tables when synched

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-database

I have some django models for my extended users profile. Problem is that this code does not create tables when syncdb is used (simply nothing happens. No validation errors). Why is that happening? (Also those models give import error elsewhere) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.signals import user_registered
from forms import ExtendedRegistrationForm
import hashlib

class InheritedProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    pid = models.CharField("PESEL", max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField("Street", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.CharField("Flat/house number", max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField("Zip ", max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField("City", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True) 
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class UserProfile(InheritedProfile):
    def upload_path(self, field_attname):
        filename = hashlib.md5(field_attname).hexdigest()[:4] + "_" + field_attname
        return "uploads/users/%s" % (filename,)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profile')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, verbose_name="Image", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
        db_table = 'userprofile'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s " % self.user.username

def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = ExtendedRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    extended_user = UserProfile(user=user)
    extended_user.is_active = False
    extended_user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    extended_user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    extended_user.pid = form.cleaned_data['pid']
    extended_user.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
    extended_user.street = form.cleaned_data['street']
    extended_user.number = form.cleaned_data['number']
    extended_user.code = form.cleaned_data['code']
    extended_user.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
    extended_user.save()

user_registered.connect(user_created)

class Friend(InheritedProfile):
    friend_of = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='friend_of')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'friend'
```

In contrary this code produces tables flawlessly :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import hashlib

class InheritedProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    pid = models.CharField("PESEL", max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField("Street", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.CharField("Flat/house number", max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField("Zip ", max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField("City", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True) 
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class UserProfile(InheritedProfile):
    def upload_path(self, field_attname):
        filename = hashlib.md5(field_attname).hexdigest()[:4] + "_" + field_attname
        return "uploads/users/%s" % (filename,)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profile')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, verbose_name="Image", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
        db_table = 'userprofile'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s " % self.user.username

class Friend(InheritedProfile):
    friend_of = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='friend_of')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'friend'
```

Should I move this user_created function somewhere else ? Signals shouldn't create problems here...

Comment: Is it possible that in `forms` you probably import `models` or a specific model?

Comment: I was importing specific models. Okay dunno why this function collided with creating tables for models, but I've moved it to a different file. Now everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you seem to have some kind of cross import; if you import some models to `forms` and some form from there back to `models` this can't be resolve, because when processing `models` `forms` is required to be imported, and `forms` requires `models` again... This can't be resolved!

Besides this I think it's better design not needing to import forms in a models module, because they are more related to views!

Comment: Circular imports resolve perfectly fine. It's attribute lookups within the modules that may not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082015/python-module-initialization-order/3082097#3082097