# django-registration creating blank django-profiles using signals

Tags: django, django-signals, django-registration, django-profiles

I have gone through the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form) and Shacker's [django-profiles: The Missing Manual](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/) and subsequent signals solution by [Dmitko](http://dmitko.ru/?p=546) and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114976/extending-django-registration-using-signals) and many places.

Here are the details:

`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "members.Profile`"

From members.models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """member model."""
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Male'),
        (2, 'Female'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), blank=True, max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True)
    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        _('gender'), 
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True,
        )
    birth_date = models.DateField(_('birth date'), blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Profiles')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Profiles')
        db_table = 'Profiles'
        ordering = ('last_name', 'first_name',)
```

From members.forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic.members.models import Profile
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm, RegistrationFormTermsOfService, RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from django.db.models import signals
from basic.members.signals import create_profile

attrs_dict = { 'class': 'required' }

class ProfileForm(RegistrationFormTermsOfService, RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Male'),
        (2, 'Female'),
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
    gender = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=GENDER_CHOICES))
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1911,1999)))

    def save(self, user):
        try:    
            data = user.get_profile()
        except:
            data = Profile(user=user)
            data.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            data.first_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            data.save()

class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)    
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

From members.signals.py:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    """When user is created also create a matching profile."""

    from basic.members.models import Profile

    if created:
        Profile(user = instance).save()
```

And members.regbackend.py:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    """When user is created also create a matching profile."""

    from basic.members.models import Profile

    if created:
        Profile(user = instance).save()
```

I am stuck. Basically my ProfileForm is adding fields to User Registration page but on saving, it is creating a User object with the username an email address but with First and Last name either in the User Object nor the Profile Object are not saved. However a blank Profile is created with the blank fields. I must be missing something small but I can't seem to see it.

So the signals are working but the data is not being saved into the profile.

Honestly, this solution in to our beloved Django should all be in one place with best practice put together for ease.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `Member` model defined? I can't even see it being imported for your `ProfileForm`. Are you putting the `ProfileForm` and `UserRegistrationForm` on the same page?

If users are filling out both forms (or even filling out the `ProfileForm`), you don't need a signal - in your `save()` for your `ProfileForm`, just have it create the profile for you:

```
   def save(self, user):
        try:    
            data = user.get_profile()
        except:
            data = Profile(user=user)
            data.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            data.first_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            data.save()
```

Comment: Hi Luke, my mistake in editing. Edited the entry. I removed the UserRegistrationForm and the signals.post_save.connect(..) and now I do not get the blank profile.

Comment: A new user is being created, but a blank Profile with none of the extended data is being saved. It seems that save function is not saving the data. What could be going wrong?