# Django-registration - How to pass the "extra_context" parameter from a subclass Form

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using Django Registration(https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/), and I need to add some fields to the registration of users.

I've made a subclass of the RegistrationForm. My "forms.py" is the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myproject.apps.userprofile.models import Gender, UserProfile
from myproject.apps.location.models import Country, City
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import RegistrationManager


class RegistrationFormExtend(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which adds the fiedls in the userprofile app
    """   
    gender              = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Gender.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
    country             = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
    city                = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
    #profile_picture     =
```

To make it work I've changed the "urls.py" to show the "RegistrationFormExtend" form by adding the "form_class" parameter to the "register" view:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from registration.views import activate
from registration.views import register

from myproject.apps.registrationextend.forms import RegistrationFormExtend


urlpatterns = patterns('',
               ...
                   url(r'^registar/$',
                       register,
                       {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', 'form_class': RegistrationFormExtend,},
                       name='registration_register'),
                   ...
                   )
```

After that, I've tested and the form is working. The user is registered successfully, but all the extra fields(gender, country, city) in the "RegistrationFormExtend" are **NOT** stored in the database.

Reading the documentation, http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html#registration.views.register it seems that I must to pass the parameter "extra_context" to the view.

My question is how to pass a dictionary to the "extra_context" parameter. How to refer to the variables "gender", "country" and "city"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined the `save` method in your extended registration form?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to have `save` method in your extended registration form. You have to do something like this:

```
class RegistrationFormExtend(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which adds the fiedls in the userprofile app
    """   
    gender = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Gender.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
    #profile_picture

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
       super(RegistrationFormExtend, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def save(self):
        #first save the parent form
        profile = super(RegistrationFormExtend, self).save()
        #then save the custom fields
        #i am assuming that the parent form return a profile
        profile.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        profile.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        profile.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        profile.save()
        return profile
```

Comment: Hi Aamir Adnan! Thanks for your reply. I have tested the save method with a "pdb.set_trace()" inside. The code does not enter inside the save method. What calls this save method? How can I make the code enter inside the save method? Thanks again.

Comment: does gender, country and city fields are even rendered in template?

Comment: Yes, the are rendered. And I see the values passing. The problem is not in the form. I'm reading the Django documentation. Should I create a "def create_user_profile" as described here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114976/extending-django-registration-using-signals will help more and this http://dewful.com/?p=70

Comment: Hi Aamir Adnan. I've tested you new solution, but is not working. I will read the links that you gave me. Many thanks for your help.