# How to add custom fields like firstname and lastname to django registration form?

Tags: django, custom-fields

I have to add two custom fields (first name, last name) into my registration form, but I don't know how. I went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934867/problem-in-adding-custom-fields-to-django-registration/3599839#3599839) but values (first name, last name) are not getting stored after registration.

Also some one tell me how to add check box to registration form using "RegistrationFormTermsOfService".

Thanks,
manu

Answer (score 0):

James Bennett has some very useful modules at http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/ that will help you along, specifically the django-registration and django-profile modules.