# Django-Registration: Account creation that asks for First Name/Last Name?

Tags: django

This question is a follow-up to the solution explained by Muki here:

[Problem in adding custom fields to django-registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934867/problem-in-adding-custom-fields-to-django-registration/14660348#14660348)

I have installed and have been successfully using the Django-registration package. By default, when you create an account using this package, it asks for your username, email address and password. I want it to also ask for (optional) first name + last name. Muki's answer at the link above explains how to do so.

However, Muki left out what should go into the file that he creates in the custom/forms.py. I need to know what the name of the class I should create in here is and what the field definitions should look like.

Can someone please post a sample forms.py that I can use to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If your custom backend is in the `custom` folder, then `custom/forms.py` could be something like this:

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm


class RegistrationFormWithName(RegistrationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

This adds your two optional fields to the default registration form. To tell your custom backend to use this new form instead of the default you need to change the `get_form_class` method in `custom/__init__.py` [Muki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935578/2035785) explains how to do that.

Of course, you'll also need to handle saving the data from the `first_name` and `last_name` fields.

**Edit**:

Your `custom/__init__.py` needs to look something like this:

```
from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend
from registration.backends.custom.forms import RegistrationFormWithName

class CustomBackend(DefaultBackend):
    def get_form_class(self, request):
        return RegistrationFormWithName
```

And `custom/urls.py` needs a line like this:

```
url(r'^register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.custom.CustomBackend'}, name='registration_register'),
```

Change the name of the `CustomBackend` class in both files to whatever you're calling your new backend.

Have a look at the [default backend source](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cdef30dc0a91ed1968be17bb1e60da4/registration/backends/default/__init__.py?at=default) to get an idea of the other methods you can override. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm lost. Still see register form with only 4 fields

custom.forms.py:

from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class RegistrationFormWithName(RegistrationForm):
    first_name=forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name=forms.CharField(required=False)

custom/__init.py__ includes:

from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.backends.custom.forms import RegistrationForm

custom/urls.py, I changed line as such:
url(r'^register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.custom.DefaultBackend'}, name='registration_register'),

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://johnparsons.net/index.php/2013/06/28/creating-profiles-with-django-registration/#comment-456)  explains the process well and works with django-registration 1.0

here are a few extra pointers in addition to the above code.

To update the first name change this in the models.py

```
def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
profile = ExUserProfile(user = user)
profile.is_human = bool(request.POST["is_human"])
user.first_name = request.POST["firstname"]
user.save()
profile.save()

user_registered.connect(user_registered_callback)
```

and in the forms.py file

```
class ExRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    is_human = forms.BooleanField(label = "Are you human?:")
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

finally to see the changes on the form create an appropriate template. The profile can be seen in the admin by creating a file called admin.py in your app and write the following code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from prof.models import ExUserProfile

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ExUserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```